# Automating the process of publishing a tableau dashboard

Tags: server, automation, tableau-api, publish

Is it possible to have your Tableau Dashboard automatically updated everyday while holding a live connection to a data source. The data source is a csv file that is updated in a specific folder everyday. Tableau holds a live connection to that csv. I am hoping there is a way to have this dashboard automatically publish to the server everyday without me having to do it manually.

If this is possible..... I could use some help/advice on how to make this happen.

Thank you for your time!